# Bash Script - return actually returns something else

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My Original Code:

```
    # Factorial Using Recursion

    res=1
    fact()
    {
        x=$1
        if [ $x -le 1 ]
        then
            echo "Actual - $res"
            return `expr $res`
        else    
            #echo $x
            res=$(($res * $x))
            echo "($res)"
            fact $[$x-1]                                
        fi
    }
    fact $1
    echo "Factorial of $1 = $?"
```

The result (stored in `$res`) is certainly what I want and is also correct. But somehow when it is being returned and caught by `$?` it becomes erroneous.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: `return` is not meant to return arbitrary data; it returns an *exit status*. To return a value, write it to standard output or put it in a global variable. (No, "proper" programming practices are not always applicable in `bash`.)

Answer (score 4):

The maximum value of a return code is `255` so there's no way that you can return the factorial of most integers.

Instead, your function should output the value to standard output, e.g. using `echo`. Capture the output of the function like `result=$(fact "$x")`.

If you want to output other messages while the function is executing then you can print to standard error using `echo 'whatever' >&2`.

```
res=1
fact()
{
    x=$1
    if [ "$x" -le 1 ]
    then
        echo "$res"
    else    
        res=$((res * x))
        fact "$((x - 1))"
    fi
}
```

I've also fixed up your syntax a little bit.

Comment: thanks! i'm new to bash :P and hence its just messing with me.